# Find 3 inverses using fewest multiplications possible

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

**Let** $a,b,c$ $\in \mathbb{Z^{^*}_p}$ with $p$ prime.

**Find** $a^{-1},b^{-1},c^{-1}$ using the fewest inverses computations and fewest multiplications.

My approach:

Compute $I = (P_1c)^{-1} = a^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}$ and the products $P_1 = ab,P_2=bc,P_3=ac$. Then the inverses are $P_4=IP_1,P_5=IP_2,P_6=IP_3$.

Let say the cost of inverse computation is $c_i$ and the cost of a multiplications is $c_m$. Then the total cost is $7c_m+c_i$ ($6 + 1$ from the product in inverse computation $+ 1$ from inverse computation) .

Could I do it better?

Comment: Compute $a\cdot b$, then $a\cdot b\cdot c$, then $I$, then $I\cdot a\cdot b$, then $I\cdot c$, then $I\cdot c\cdot a$ and $I\cdot c\cdot b$. That's $6c_m+c_i$.

Comment: I don't know how the 'score' is computed, but one can compute them with no inverse computation and $O(\ln p)$ multiplications by using Fermat's little theorem, and of course 3 inverse computation and no multiplication.